# "ReferenceError: is not defined" allthough listed as script in html file

Tags: javascript, html

ReferenceError allthough function is defined.

tried renaming

```
<body>
   <script>
    function yaSuggestion() {
      console.log("hello");
      var input = document.getElementById("yaIsInput");
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

      request.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/issues/get");
      request.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
          //console.log(request.responseText);
        } else {
          //console.warn(request.statusText, request.responseText);
        }
      });
      request.send();
      request.onreadystatechange = processRequest();
      function processRequest() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
          console.log(request.responseText);
          var res = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
          var suggestions = [];
          for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            suggestions.push(res[i].value);
          };
          console.log(suggestions);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
<input type="text" name="yaIsInput" class="form-control" id="yaIsInput" onchange="yaSuggestion()">
</body>
```

expected: console output "hello"
actual: ReferenceError: yaSuggestion is not defined[Learn More] ya_create:1:1

Comment: Should be closed because the problem is caused by a typo. Deal with the **first** error first. You have a stray `}` that prevents the function from being defined.

Comment: The typo was limited to the question version, which is now updated. Error persists.

Comment: The error **does not** persist. The live demo (after your edit) in the question works: https://i.imgur.com/2sloLBc.png

Comment: True. Updated the code snippet to show my actual code. If I run it like this, then the error might occur. Hope you can help here as well.

Comment: Typo: `processRequest();` has an extra `()` so it calls the function imediately (before the readyState has changed) so the condition `request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200` is never true, so it does nothing. You should be using the load event handler instead.

Comment: I ve put the logic of processRequest() to the event listener:
request.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
          if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
            var res = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var suggestions = [];
            for (int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
              suggestions.push(res[i].value);
            };
            console.log(suggestions);
      
          }
        } 
      });
Still not working

Answer (score 1):

Hi first thing you have an additional closing '}' in your script :

use this

```js
 function yaSuggestion() {
          console.log("hello");
          }
```

second you have to import your script before calling the function :

```html
   <body>
      <script>
        function yaSuggestion() {
          console.log("hello");
          }
      </script>
      <input type="text" name="yaIsInput" class="form-control" id="yaIsInput" onchange="yaSuggestion()">
    </body>
```

Comment: The order the code appears in does not matter in this case.

Comment: @Quentin thank you for pointing that out, I agree with you it won't matter in this case, it is just a good practice to have the script imported before it is used.